# Geting only the max value

Tags: select, max

The folowing code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id1, A1.Id2
FROM    Table A1 
WHERE   1 <=
        (SELECT COUNT (*)
        FROM    Table A2
        WHERE   A1.Id2 = A2.Id2)
```

outputs :

```
                  ID1       ID2
-------------------- ----------
                   1          1
                   1          2
                   2          3
                   3          4
                   5          6
                   5          7
```

but I want to get the only one ID1 with the maximum value of ID2
like this :

```
                  ID1       ID2
-------------------- ----------
                   1          2
                   2          3
                   5          7
```

what do I do wrong ?

Comment: And the contents of A1 and A2 are...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if this helps.

SELECT A1.ID1, MAX(A2.ID2)
FROM    Table A1, TABLE A2
WHERE   A1.ID2=A2.ID2
GROUP BY A1.ID1

Comment: You are welcome. Please vote this up to show as the answer. Thanks!